# Converting xml data which is present in a dataframe column in to multiple columns using spark scala

Tags: sql, xml, dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have df which contains 4 columns(colA, colB, colC & colD), In that colD alone contains string data which is present as xml data like below, I need to extract the tag's (AN, SOF, LEN, BN, COC, LA, ST, CT, ZN,TI, PN, PF, PB) and make it as individual column in df

```
<variable type="DL" container="EFAO">
  <DD type="String"><![CDATA[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]]></DD>
  <SDI type="String"><![CDATA[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]]></SDI>
  <AL type="ACC[]"> 
    <item>
        <AN type="String"><![CDATA[000000000]]></AN>
        <FD type="FD">
            <SOF type="String"><![CDATA[XXXXXXXXXXX]]></SOF>
            <LEN type="String"><![CDATA[XXXXXXXXXXX]]></LEN>
            <BN type="String"><![CDATA[XXXXXXXXXXXXXX]]></BN>
            <COC type="String"><![CDATA[XX]]></COC>
            <LA type="String"><![CDATA[XXXXXXXXXXXXX]]></LA>
            <ST type="String"><![CDATA[XXXXXXXXXXXX]]></ST>
            <CT type="String"><![CDATA[XXXXXXXXXXXXX]]></CT>
            <ZN type="String"><![CDATA[XX]]></ZN>
            <TI type="String"><![CDATA[XXXXXX]]></TI>
            <PN type="String"><![CDATA[1234567]]></PN>
            <PF type="String"><![CDATA[sdgfcghj]]></PF>
            <PB type="String"><![CDATA[1234asd]]></PB>
        </FD>
   </item>
  </AL>
```

Below is the code which I tried

```
val Schema = new StructType().add("AL", new StructType().add("item", new ArrayType(new StructType().add("FD", new ArrayType(new StructType().add("SOF", StringType, true).add("LEN", StringType, true).add("BN", StringType, true).add("COC", StringType, true).add("LA", StringType, true).add("ST", StringType, true).add("CT", StringType, true).add("ZN", StringType, true).add("TI", StringType, true).add("PN", StringType, true).add("PF", StringType, true).add("PB", StringType, true), true), true), true)), true)

val transformedDF = inputdf.withColumn("parsed", from_xml($"colD", Schema))

spark.conf.set("spark.xml.rowTag","parsed")

val df1= transformedDF.select(col("parsed.*"))

val df2= df1.select("AL.item.FD")

val df3 = df2.selectExpr("inline_outer(FD)")
```

I'm not getting desired output, kindly help me on this

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

The xpath family of functions can be used, although the examples are text it will work on columns as well - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#xpath

The xml is however parsed for each row once per each xpath call/column.  You can use the non typed xpath to speed that up though and process the strings into correct types later.

Given you have from_xml in your comment I assume you are on databricks, but in order to help further using from_xml we'd need to see what you actually get from your output and what you want to get.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the Databricks' Spark XML API.

Firstly, you need to import this in your maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
     <artifactId>spark-xml_(scala_version_that_you_use)</artifactId>
     <version>0.6.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

Then, you can do like the following:

```
val xmlDf = spark.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
      .option("rowTag", "item")
      .xml("<your_xml_file_path>")
```

I see that you want all the columns under `<item>` as separate columns, hence item tag is provided in the `rowTag` option. Please note that this will infer schema on its own.

Alternatively, you can define your own schema too.

Comment: Actually I don't get data in xml's, currently the data is present in an individual string column in a table in xml format, the changelling part is to parse the string column and transpose the xml format data in to individual columns